# How Web Application in Appcelerator Market are linked with Titanium

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I was just exploring Appcelerator market place and found a web Application category in it. Tried to download some free web Application. As after purchasing that web Application(the free one) i didn't got any files downloaded, which i can use in my Application, they all take me to there website.

And I wanted to know that why those Application are in the market place? Are they build using Titanium studio? If yes then how they can be coupled with my Application.

Though some of them exposes there API, so we can integrate them in our Application. If exposing API is the only thing here, then I can build any Web application(not with Titanium studio) expose my API and upload to the Appcelerator market place.
So to cut it short How the Web Application in market Place are linked with Titanium Studio.

Comment: give me an example please. Because the marketplace is full of modules you can load into your titanium studio

Comment: @Topener not about the modules i am talking about Web Applications in market place like sendGrid, SnapEngage, YastTimeTracker, etc

Comment: Titanium Studio is an Eclipse-based IDE built on the patent-pending development technology acquired from Aptana™. Use Titanium Studio to rapidly build, test and deploy mobile, desktop and web applications. Take advantage of new functionality like code completion, Git integration and a full-featured editor. Manage Titanium projects, test your mobile apps in the simulator or on device, automate app packaging and much more … all from within the new Titanium Studio.    http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-studio/

Comment: @rajesh.adhi I know all this may be my question is not clear to you. I just want to know How the Web Application present on the appcelerator market place are linked to Titanium studio, are they build using Titanium studio or any web application can be uploaded on Appcelerator market

Comment: yes they are build using titanium studio, in titanium studio we have option to create web mobile and desktop applications, that is what the link implies